# how to make multiline wx.ListBox

Tags: python, wxpython

I need a ListBox to show a phone book.Then i need to show name in top and number in bottom in each list item like phone.how to bind the datas into listbox.

now i made a listbox with singleline as shown below

```
    cur.execute("select fname from tblsample1 order by fname")
    names = [str(item[0]) for item in cur.fetchall()]
    lvnames=wx.ListBox(panel,-1,(10,40),(210,180),names, wx.LB_SINGLE)
```

how to bind sqlite3 cursor with two columns to the listview

i need a wx.ListBox mouse click event(not EVT_LISTBOX 
 because i need only mouse click event)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [HtmlListBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxhtmllistbox.html), here is a little example to get you started.

```
import wx


class PhoneNumbers(wx.HtmlListBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.HtmlListBox.__init__(self, parent)
        self.data = [
            ("Foo", "3452-453"),
            ("Bar", "5672-346"),
        ]
        self.SetItemCount(len(self.data))

    def OnGetItem(self, n):
        return "<b>%s</b><br>%s" % self.data[n]

    def add_number(self, name, number):
        self.data.append((name, number))
        self.SetItemCount(len(self.data))
        self.Refresh()


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(200, 400))

        self.numbers = PhoneNumbers(self)
        self.contact_name = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.contact_number = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.add_btn = wx.Button(self, label="Add contact")

        self.Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Sizer.Add(self.numbers, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Sizer.Add(wx.SearchCtrl(self), 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label="Name"), 0, wx.TOP, 10)
        self.Sizer.Add(self.contact_name)
        self.Sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label="Number"), 0, wx.TOP, 5)
        self.Sizer.Add(self.contact_number)
        self.Sizer.Add(self.add_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.numbers.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnSelectNumber)
        self.add_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddNumber)

    def OnSelectNumber(self, event):
        name, number = self.numbers.data[event.Selection]
        self.contact_name.Value = name
        self.contact_number.Value = number

    def OnAddNumber(self, event):
        self.numbers.add_number(
            self.contact_name.Value,
            self.contact_number.Value
        )


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = f = Frame()
f.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: how to add two TextCtrl to HtmlListBox?

Comment: You can't use a ListBox for editing, look in to wxGrid for that.

Comment: If you mean to add controls *besides* a listbox use sizers. You can't add any control *in* a listbox. If you add a sketch of what you want to accomplish in your question I will write some code for you.

Comment: i need a listview.in each list there should be names in bolder lettr and phone number in next line as in the mobile phones.i am creting a phone book like program. __thank you__

Comment: You didn't say anything I don't know. Add a picture to your question of what you want your UI to look like.

Comment: http://mos.futurenet.com/techradar/Review%20images/TechRadar/Mobile%20phones/Nokia/E7/screengrabs/7-210-100.jpg      `need a list view as shown this picture`

Comment: Doubts? Study the docs, try stuff out and if all else fails ask more questions ;)

Comment: Only problem with this is that HtmlListBox doesn't seem to break/wrap words if they are too long. It doesn't respond to the <wbr> tag, nor the zero-width-space unicode characters from my experiments. <br/> works, but it doesn't help if you want the break to happen 'naturally'. I'm trying to break long words in a drop-down HtmlListBox which can potentially have dynamic width if in a sizer. I could use dc.GetMultiLineTextExtent but that won't take into account other HTML styles that might work in a HtmlListBox. I guess I'll just try dc.GetMultiLineTextExtent with a VListBox and inserting \n

Comment: The example in this answer does not run on the current version of wxPython. I made some slight modifications so that it runs on the latest wxPython.
https://pastebin.com/zJv8ZHx1

Answer (score 1):

You should rephrase your question, I don't know if I got this right.

If you only need to display the two lines in your `ListBox`, you could simply use a `\n`:

```
cur.execute("select fname,number from tblsample1 order by fname")
entries = [str(item[0])+'\n'+str(item[1]) for item in cur.fetchall()]
```

To get a 'click' Event, you cant set the style of your `wx.ListBox` to `wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL` and catch the selection event `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`

Comment: i need the fname should display in bold letter and it should be larger than number.`Thank You`

Comment: Then you should go with `HtmlListBox` as mentioned by Toni Ruza. Hava a look into the demo, looks promising.